# Does it make sense to kill a character in the middle of a character arc, or in order to not finish the character arc?

Tags: creative-writing, characters, character-development

Does it make sense to kill a character in the middle of a character arc, or in order to not finish the character arc? If you notice that a character arc is forcing yourself to write yourself into a corner, does it make sense to abruptly kill that character in the middle of it, even though his character arc isn't finished?

I am wondering if it goes against the rules and the cons outweigh the pros, or this is actually a viable strategy to not finish a character arc you don't want to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you kill off one of several characters, it can work. Think war stories. Think slasher-flicks. Think many science fiction monster-in-the-dark movies. Think a story about a lethal epidemic. Think historical dramas involving somebody losing a close relative.  Think many detective stories.

The people who remain behind can be interesting for their reactions. How do they cope with the loss? Does it make them morose? Or does it energize them to make something of their lives? How do they mourn?

There are also some stories written as retrospectives. People will remember the life of the dead person.

There is also the "It's a Wonderful Life" trope. What would the world be like if you died now? You need to work pretty hard for that not to be cliché.

So you probably need something besides the single character who dies. Otherwise, when the character dies, the story is over. You need other characters or some process or background thing or something.

Comment: Who downvoted the question?